# jQuery datatable doesn't read property 'row'; how can I select a row while rendering a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable

Select row on datatable when rendering does not work.
When rendering checkbox is checked but datatable throws error that it can 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'row')'.

Is it even possible?

Code

```
function renderTable(data) {
    if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#My_Datatable_Id')) {
        $('#My_Datatable_Id').DataTable().destroy();
    }

    $('#My_Datatable_Id tfoot th').each(function () {
        $(this).html('');
    });

    var tableMyPrivileges = $('#My_Datatable_Id').DataTable({
        data: data,
        responsive: true,
        pageLength: 10,
        order: [],
        columns: [
            { data: "name" },
            {
                data: "is_active", render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    if (data == true) {
                        activeGroups.push(data);
                        return '<center><input type="checkbox" checked></center>'
                    } else {
                        return '<center><input type="checkbox"></center>';
                    }
                }
            },
        ],
        columnDefs: [{
            targets: 2,
            orderable: false,
        },
        {
            targets: [0, 1],
            orderable: false
        }
        ],
        select: {
            style: 'multi',
            selector: 'td:last-child input[type="checkbox"]'
        },
        rowGroup: {
            dataSrc: 'group'
        },
        rowCallback: function (row, data, dataIndex) {
            var checkbox = $(row).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
            if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
                //$(row).select();
                //$(row).toggleClass('selected');      //SELECTS ROW BUT IS NOT PASSED TO DATATABLE
                tableMyPrivileges.row(row).select();   //THROWS ERROR
            }
        },
    //rest of funtion
```

tried rowcallback and created row, rendering in different places... none work

Comment: Can you setup a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

To handle the initial display of your table, you can use a modified version of your `rowCallback` code to select a row based on the state of its checkbox:

```js
rowCallback: function (row, data, dataIndex) {
  var checkbox = $(row).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
  var api = $( '#My_Datatable_Id' ).DataTable();
  if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
      api.row( row ).select();
  } else {
      api.row( row ).deselect();
  }
}
```

You can access the [DataTables API](https://datatables.net/manual/api) inside the row callback using:

```
var api = $( '#My_Datatable_Id' ).DataTable();
```

You can then use this `api` object to select - and also deselect - the relevant rows.

This uses the fact that you can pass a row node to the [`row()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row()) API call. See [row-selector](https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector) for a list of all the ways you can call `row()`.

---

Here is a demo:

```js
var data = [{
    "is_active": true,
    "name": "Tiger Nixon",
    "position": "System Architect",
    "salary": "$320,800",
    "start_date": "2011/04/25",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "5421"
  },
  {
    "is_active": false,
    "name": "Donna Snider",
    "position": "Customer Support",
    "salary": "$112,000",
    "start_date": "2011/01/25",
    "office": "New York",
    "extn": "4226"
  },
  {
    "is_active": true,
    "name": "Cedric Kelly",
    "position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
    "salary": "$433,060",
    "start_date": "2012/03/29",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "6224"
  },
  {
    "is_active": false,
    "name": "Airi Satou",
    "position": "Accountant",
    "salary": "$162,700",
    "start_date": "2008/11/28",
    "office": "Tokyo",
    "extn": "5407"
  },
  {
    "is_active": false,
    "name": "Brielle Williamson",
    "position": "Integration Specialist",
    "salary": "$372,000",
    "start_date": "2012/12/02",
    "office": "New York",
    "extn": "4804"
  }
];

$(document).ready(function() {

  var tableMyPrivileges = $('#My_Datatable_Id').DataTable({
    data: data,
    responsive: true,
    pageLength: 10,
    order: [],
    columns: [{
        data: "is_active",
        render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
          if (data == true) {
            return '<center><input type="checkbox" checked></center>'
          } else {
            return '<center><input type="checkbox"></center>';
          }
        }
      },
      {
        data: "name"
      },
      {
        data: "position"
      },
    ],
    columnDefs: [{
        targets: 2,
        orderable: true,
      },
      {
        targets: [0, 1],
        orderable: false
      }
    ],
    select: {
      style: 'multi',
      selector: 'td:last-child input[type="checkbox"]'
    },
    rowCallback: function(row, data, dataIndex) {
      var checkbox = $(row).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
      var api = $('#My_Datatable_Id').DataTable();
      if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
        api.row(row).select();
      } else {
        api.row(row).deselect();
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.6.2/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.6.2/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="My_Datatable_Id" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Selected</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The above demo does not use any `rowGroup` functionality, since that is not relevant to your question.

I also enabled sorting to show that the selected rows remain selected when you perform sorting.

---

**To Do**

This demo does not contain any logic to select (or deselect) a row when the user clicks on a checkbox - but you can create a JavaScript event handler for your checkboxes and apply a similar approach to the one I use here.

There are also many questions already on Stack Overflow covering how to select a DataTable row when its checkbox is checked/unchecked.